# ReferenceError: artifacts is not defined running Truffle Test

Tags: truffle

I am trying to execute the built in until test provided in the metacoin example. I installed Mocha into my project.

I then execute this command: `npm test` from my console.

I am getting the following error:

`C:\Dev\Blockchain\TruffleDemo\test\metacoin.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var MetaCoin = artifacts.require("./MetaCoin.sol");
                                                                                       ^
ReferenceError: artifacts is not defined`

Any ideas on what I might be missing? Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: Please run `truffle test` instead of `npm test`

Comment: @rstormsf - Thanks, that worked! If you want to post as the answer; I will mark it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `truffle test` instead of `npm test`

Comment: I am already doing so...